# What node js returns to the client when it waits for the response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am new to nodejs but i am aware of asynchronous model of javascript in general. I come from grails/servlet background. In servlet, when request is sent to the server everything is synchronous, it computes the result and send it back to the client. If the result takes long then we thread it and store it somewhere to retrieve it later but the response is not hold rather another request is performed to get the result.
In nodejs however, my understanding so far is it waits for the response until it is computed from some asynchronous callbacks.
Now my assumption is, nodejs must return something to the client because the javascript callstack doesn't wait for the return. But NO, the proper response is sent to the client. 
Now my question is how the client waits until it gets the response from the callbacks or some promises?
Here is an example:

```
var express = require('express');
var {mongoose} = require('./db/mongoose');
var {User} = require('./models/user');

var app = express();
app.get('/users',(req,res)=>{
   User.find().then((result)=>{ // here response is calculated inside then
                                // which is retrieved later at this point how nodejs waits for 
                                //   this result
      res.send(result)
   },(e)=>{

     });
}); 

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now my assumption is, nodejs must return something to the client because the javascript callstack doesn't wait for the return.

It doesn't.

> Now my question is how the client waits until it gets the response from the callbacks or some promises?

It just … waits. It doesn't need to be told to wait. It knows that sending a message over the network won't get an instant response.

If too much time passes before it gets a response, then it will timeout and give up.

Comment: Hmm.. so getting the response after a request is must as from http protocol, that is why the client waits for the response until nodejs server sends something as the response, Right? @Quentin

Answer (score -1):

Nodejs will be wait for the response and Node Js doesn't do anything for wait for the response. But if you wants to set any user prevent interface then you can use any library for it.

If client gets too much time for wait then nodejs itself throw any exception (if there are issue will be happen at server side) or timeout.